# How to read avro data from kafka console consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I am experimenting with Spring Boot + Kafka + Avro. Producing and consuming messages work in the Java IDE, but I want to know if it's possible to view the Avro messages produced on the topic using the kafka-console-consumer tool provided with Kafka installation (so, basically view on the console).

I have the following setup:

1. Apache Kafka (3.1.0)
2. Spring Cloud Schema Registry Server (1.2)
3. Spring Boot (3.1.0) + Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Kafka + Spring Cloud Stream Schema Registry Client: This is an application producing Avro messages.
4. Spring Boot (3.1.0) + Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Kafka + Spring Cloud Stream Schema Registry Client: This is an application consuming Avro messages.

The above works. However, I am trying to also view the data on my console using kafka-console-consumer.bat (provided with Kafka Windows installation). However, I am unable to view the data.

I use kafka-console-consumer with the following parameters:

```
./kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-topic -from-beginning 
--property print.key=true --property key.separator=':' --property print.headers=true 
--property value.converter=org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.registry.avro.AvroSchemaMessageConverter 
--property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8990
```

Any ideas if it's possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.